# How can we theoretically prove that the chromatic number of the graph is 5?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

It's easy for us to determine the chromatic number of the graph below as $5$ using a computer program. However, I'm struggling to find a theoretical explanation.

[image]

Since the chromatic number of a graph must be greater than or equal to its clique number,  its chromatic number must be at least 4. Furthermore, we have also found a 5-coloring solution (see also the figure).

How can we theoretically demonstrate that the chromatic number of the graph is exactly 5 (rather than relying on algorithmic approaches)?

Comment: Are the blue dashed lines edges in the graph?

Comment: @EricNathanStucky Yes,  they all belong to the graph.

Comment: A semi-usefull theoretical result is that the chromatic number is at most one more than the highest occuring degree of any vertex, which in your graph seems to be 4. So this limits the options to 4 or 5. So this would save you the 'trouble' of finding a 5-coloring. But the hard part is ruling out that graph is 4-colorable. I can't think of any easy argument there.

Comment: Well, maybe this useful. If there were a 4-coloring, at least one of the monochromatic cocliques must have at least 6 elements. If there are no cocliques of size 6 then no 4-coloring can exist. Checking all cocliques is still a lot of work, but maybe less than checking all colorings

Comment: Of course generally speaking using theoretical arguments is easier if we have a more theoretical description of the graph. E.g. if it is a sceleton of an archimedian polyhedron, or the Cayley graph of some group or something else that allows us to derive some 'theoretical' properties like symmetries then checking non-existence of large cocliques might be a lot easier

Comment: @Vincent It appears to be the skeleton of the [pseudo-rhombicuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_square_gyrobicupola), but with every square face replaced by a clique.

Comment: @MishaLavrov You are right. I forgot to mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $\chi(G)>4$ we need to argue that there is no proper 4-coloring. As mentioned in the comments, doing this in a nice way often requires a nice description of the graph*. However, because of the prevalence of $K_4$'s in the graph it is tedious but not too difficult to give a "sudoku" proof.

Suppose for sake of contradiction that a 4-coloring $\chi$ exists. WLOG we may assume
$$\chi(1)=1 \quad \chi(4)=2 \quad \chi(9)=3 \quad \chi(3)=4$$

Thus the vertices 5 and 11 must have colors 3 and 4 between them.

---

**Case I.** Suppose that indeed
$$\chi(5)=3 \quad \chi(11)=4 $$
We claim that this fixes the "exterior" of the triangle. The vertices 2 and 6 must have colors 2 and 4 between them because of the lower $K_4$, but since $\{2,3\}\in E$:
$$\chi(2)=2 \quad \chi(6)=4$$
Similarly vertices 7 and 13 must have colors 1 and 3 between them, and vertices 8 and 15 must have colors 1 and 2 between them. But since $\{2,8\}\in E$ it must be
$$\chi(13)=1 \quad \chi(7)=3 \quad \chi(8)=1 \quad \chi(15)=2$$

Now go "in one layer" on the right side to see that the vertices 10 and 16 must have colors 1 and 4 between them, and so it must be
$$\chi(10)=1 \quad \chi(16)=4$$
On the other two sides of the triangle we don't have a $K_4$ but vertices 12 and 14 are already adjacent to a lot of determined vertices and we immediately get
$$\chi(12)=2 \quad \chi(14)=4$$
$$\chi(19)=3 \quad \chi(20)=2$$
Therefore vertices 23 and 24 must have colors 1 and 4 between them, and since $\{14,24\}\in E$ we have
$$\chi(23)=4 \quad \chi(24)=1$$
Thus we find a contradiction with vertices 21 and 22: both are adjacent to vertices colored 1, 2, and 4; but they cannot both be colored 3 since they are adjacent.

---

**Case II.** To avoid confusion with previous assumptions, change the name of the coloring to $\psi$. We still have
$$\psi(1)=1 \quad \psi(4)=2 \quad \psi(9)=3 \quad \psi(3)=4$$
but now we are supposing that instead
$$\psi(5)=4 \quad \psi(11)=3 $$
Now the vertices 2 and 6 must have colors 2 and 3 between them because of the lower $K_4$, and thus vertices 7 and 13 must have colors 1 and 4 between them. Since $\{3,7\}\in E$:
$$\chi(7)=1 \quad \chi(13)=4$$
As before, vertices 8 and 15 must have colors 1 and 2 between them. But since $\{7,8\}\in E$ and then $\{2,8\}\in E$, it must be
$$\psi(8)=2 \quad \psi(15)=1 \quad \psi(2)=3 \quad \psi(6)=2$$

This fixes the exterior as before. Going in one layer and proceeding in the same way yields
$$\psi(10)=1 \quad \psi(16)=4$$
$$\psi(12)=1 \quad \psi(14)=3$$
This time we find a contradiction faster: we cannot color the vertex 21, since it is adjacent to vertices 15, 8, 14, and 16 which respectively are colored 1, 2, 3 and 4.

---

Although this argument has obvious disadvantages, it does at least have the benefit of making it quite easy to find a 5-coloring: start with $\chi$ but then when it is time for the contradiction, simply color $\chi(22)=5$ instead, and it is easy to find colors for the last pair of vertices.

I suspect that a proof will require at least as much sudoku as fixing the exterior of the triangle. A more intelligent line of reasoning might proceed by saying: "Okay there are only two ways to make a locally proper coloring around a triangle. But to extend to a global proper coloring we need to be able to make the local colorings agree around each of the eight triangles, and we'll now argue this is impossible."

[ * Misha Lavrov provided such a description in the comments: your graph is the skeleton (just the vertices and edges) of the [pseudo-rhombicuboctohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_square_gyrobicupola), with each square face replaced by a $K_4$. Unfortunately it is not the square of the 1-skeleton, since if it were there would be an easy argument. One thing that it is much easier to do with the polyhedron in hand is to chase down Vincent's idea. Breaking the vertices into "layers" it's not hard to argue that any coclique (or independent set, if you prefer) has size at most 6, and so each color class in a 4-coloring must have exactly 6 elements.

Although I think I "see" the proof more clearly with the 3D visual, I didn't find any easier way to write down the argument. In particular, there do exist size-6 cocliques, and it's even easy to get two of them disjoint. I am almost certain that it is possible to find three disjoint ones, but it is not so easy to explain why they cannot be adjusted to add in the fourth. ]