# Given a fixed set of colors, what is the maximum number of vertices that can be colored?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

The chromatic number $\chi(G)$ of a graph $G$ is the smallest number of colors needed to color the vertices of $G$ so that no two adjacent vertices share the same color.

I'm not certain if the following problem  has been researched before.

**Problem 1.** Given $k$ different colors, what is the maximum number of vertices in a graph  that one can color using only these $k$ colors?

I recall this problem coming from the [previous link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4755939/how-can-we-theoretically-prove-that-the-chromatic-number-of-the-graph-is-5/4756040#4756040). Graph $G$ is  the skeleton of the pseudo-rhombicuboctahedron  with every square face replaced by a clique. Using 4 colors isn't sufficient to color all the vertices of $G$ （thanks to Eric Nathan Stucky). However, what's interesting is, with these 4 colors, what is the maximum number of vertices of $G$ that can be colored? Of course, if an **algorithm** can be developed, it would be even more helpful for analyzing certain graphs.

I've abstracted it, though. I believe this problem might have been studied by researchers in the past.

---

Taking it further.

**Problem 2.**  Color (fixed) $k$ vertices of $G$ with these $k$ colors first (ensuring adjacent vertices have distinct colors), is it possible to efficiently determine an upper bound on the number of vertices in $G$ that can be colored?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376046/relations-between-optimization-versions-of-k-coloring-and-max-k-colorable-induce

Comment: @MishaLavrov Nice. The first problem is the **Maximum $k$-Colorable Subgraph Problem**.